# Perl script running a periodic (main) task and providing a REST interface

Tags: rest, perl, software-design, multitasking, dancer

I am working on a Perl script which does some periodic processing based on file-system contents.
The overall structure is like this:

```
# ... initialization...

while(1) {
    # ... scan filesystem, perform actions depending on changes detected ...
    sleep 5;
}
```

I would like to add the ability to input some data into this process by means of exposing an interface through HTTP. E.g. I would like to add an endpoint to skip the sleep, but also some means to input data that is processed in the next iteration. Additionally, I would like to be able to query some of the program's status through HTTP (i.e. a simple `fork()` to run the webserver-part in a separate process is insufficient?)

So far I have already used the `Dancer2` framework once but it has a `start;` call that blocks and thus does not allow any other tasks (like my loop) to run. Additionally, I could of course move the code which is currently inside the loop to an endpoint exposed through `Dancer2` but then I would need to call that periodically (though an external program?) which seems to be quite an obscure indirection compared to just having the webserver-part running in background.

Is it possible to unobtrusively (i.e. without blocking the program) add a REST-server capability to a Perl script? If yes: Which modules would be used for the purpose? If no: Should I really implement an external process to periodically invoke a certain endpoint or pursue a different solution altogether?

(I have tried to add a `dancer2` tag, but could not do so due to insufficient reputation. Do not be mislead by this: I have so far only tried with `Dancer2` not the `Dancer` (v.1))

Comment: It might be best/simplest to output the job's status (e.g. to a JSON file) to be used by an independent web server.

Comment: @ikegami: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Actually, most data that should be returned to the client is already available in files, so that would work well. On the other side, this would still not allow any "interaction" in the sense that the HTTP request cancels the sleep or causes different data to be processed in the next loop iteration?

Comment: dunno about ```dancer``` but in the old days we solve a problem like this with [select](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) because it cans listening (http) handlers and takes the last parameter as the timeout

Comment: @T'East: Thank you very much. I think `select` may work in this case. I will need to have a look into how I can avoid writing "my own webserver" in the end (just for a few endpoints :) ), but that should be doable :). Thinking of it, while the main loop processes data, a select-based server will likely not answer any requests? Could be acceptable as of now, but I still think there should be a better solution?

Comment: [Mojolicious](https://mojolicious.org) is ideal for combining a web server with your own non-blocking tasks, through its integrated event loop. Though I would still recommend two different services that communicate via a database.

Comment: @linux-fan do you have access to any caching (e.g.Redis) or any other lite DB that you can use to keep state. The script can sleep and/or skip sleep, scan filesystem and perform actions based on the state stored in the cache. Your rest actions can update/set the state in the cache

Comment: Thanks all for the good suggestions. I will have a look into Mojolicious and think of how complex it is to integrate a database (there are no hard restrictions against it really, I am just trying to keep the design as simple as possible :) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to launch your processing loop in a background thread, before you run `start;`.

See `man perlthrtut`

You probably want `use threads::shared;` to declare some variables shared between the REST part and the background thread. Or use dedicated queues/event mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I think I now have a lot of things to try :) . Once I know how it worked in the end, I will report the results here and "accept" an answer. Two things immediately come to my mind thinking of implementing this with Threads: (1) I know that Dancer provides an integrated logging mechanism. Can I still use that logging mechanism (for custom logs from my thread) by just calling the log routines from the separate thread (I woudl think the answer is no, but maybe I have overlooked something?), (2) Is there any specific reason for using `shared` over queues?

Comment: In recent times, I finally managed to work out a solution. And in the end it was exactly this: The processing loop is now in a background thread, taking requests through a queue. Additionally, the periodic check is in a separate loop -- performing checks at regular intervals and finally, the REST interface is implemented with Dancer2. Thanks all :)